# Validation of regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, validation, data-annotations

Need to verify data input with the attribute [`RegularExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx), while on a property goes several regular expressions, for example:

```
     [RegularExpression (@ "[a-z] {4,} ", ErrorMessage ="Short Name")]
     [RegularExpression (@ "[a-z]", ErrorMessage = "invalid character ")]
     public string Name {set; get;}
```

The use of two attributes RegularExpression compiler issues
"Duplicate 'RegularExpression' attribute".

how to implement a verification?

Comment: As a comment, I’d much rather if you didn’t restrict the set of characters users could use, much less to such a small English-centric set of letters. Would you consider removing that restriction from your application to avoid angering your users?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom attributes:

```
public class ShortNameAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public ShortNameAttribute() : base(@"[a-z] {4,} ")
    {
    }
}
public class InvalidCharsAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public InvalidCharsAttribute() : base(@"[a-z]")
    {
    }
}


[ShortNameAttribute]
[InvalidCharsAttribute] 
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hm... if this works, why is `RegularExpressionAttribute` declared with `AllowMultiple=false`?

Comment: @Timwi well set it true then.

Comment: [I don't think he can tamper too much with it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) :P